# How to compare all arguments in bash

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to write bash script to take an argument from any number of arguments and compare it to a string, when i run the program it errors saying it has to many arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
flag=( 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 )
let count=2
while [ "$count" -lt 17 ]
do
        if [ $* = with${count} ]
        then
                let flag[$count]=1
        fi
        if [ $* = sans${count} ]
        then
                let flag[$count]=0
        fi
        let count=$count+1
done
```

Is there a way to compare all arguments to the string?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear at all. Could you please, after having a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), post the commands you are issuing and the output you are expecting?  Using `$*` and not `"$*"` is surely an issue, but using quotes will make the errors go away, it won’t produce the expected results (whatever they are).

Comment: It appears you are looking for `[[ $haystack =~ $needle ]]` (or in your case, e.g. `[[ $* =~ with${count} ]]` You cannot use `[ ... ]` because it requires only one argument on either side. `$*` will enter many. Further, if you want to identify which argument the substring matched, then you should iterate over each of the arguments and test individually.

Comment: There are couple of issues with your logic. For ex, in the loop you are using `"` double quotes to make `$count` as a "string" type and comparing it with # 17 using a numerical operator `-lt`. Remove the `"` in the while loop's condition statement/line.